# MapboxGL JS animate transition GeoJSON feature opacity

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I have a GeoJSON layer with real estate lots added as a source to my Mapbox map.  When a user clicks on a specific lot, my creative team wants the lot to pulse or have it's opacity fading from .1 to .7 constantly repeating until we remove the active state.  I added an active feature state to the selected lot and the coloring is all working fine, however I'm not sure if it's possible to achieve a continuous fade in/out while that feature is active.  Is this possible in MapboxGL JS?

I've attached a picture of the colored in lot.

[image]

We also used to be using Google Maps for this project and was able to achieve the desired effect, so I created a GIF to be clear on what we're looking for.

[image]

Anyone know?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[`fill-color`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#paint-fill-fill-color) is a transitionable property, so when you change the opacity, it will visually transition over a short time - by default, 300ms.

To achieve what you want:

- create a timer loop using window.setInterval()
- inside, set the layer's opacity using `map.setPaintProperty('mylayer', 'fill-opacity', ...)`
- Optionally, control the transition duration with a [`transition`](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/transition/) property on the layer in your style definition.